# Why are we talking about homeomorphisms from these definitions? The question comes from differential geometry.

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

I fear that it is hard to explain precisely my confusion. The actual question is: **What are the necessary/sufficient conditions for $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ to have a continuous inverse function?**

Why am I asking this is the confusing part. In fact, I think it's better if you can help me with the confusion, the question above is the worst case scenario. First let me give three equivalent definitions for a smooth sub-manifold:

> 1. $S$ is a smooth sub-manifold if for every $x \in S$, there exists an open set $x \in U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and a submersion $f:U \to \mathbb{R}^k$ such that $f^{-1}(\vec0) = S \cap U$, where $\vec0 \in \mathbb{R}^k$

> 2. $S$ is a smooth sub-manifold if for every $x \in S$, there exists an open set $x \in V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and a diffeomorphism $g:V \to W \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $g(S \cap V) = \{\mathbb{R}^{n-k} \times \{\vec0\}\} \cap W$, where $\vec0 \in \mathbb{R}^k$

> 3. $S$ is a smooth sub-manifold if for every $x \in S$, there exist open sets $x \in \tilde{V} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\tilde{W} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$, along with $\psi:\tilde{W} \to \tilde{V}$ an injective immersion such that $S \cap \tilde{V}$ is the image of $\psi$.

I might as well provide the definitions of immersion, submersion, and diffeomorphism that we are using.

Let $n,k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, and let $f:U \to \mathbb{R}^k$ where $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$:

> 4. f is an immersion if for all $x \in U$, $D_xf$ is injective. This is only possible when $n \leq k$, and if the Jacobian has full rank

> 5. f is an submersion if for all $x \in U$, $D_xf$ is surjective. This is only possible when $n \geq k$, and if the Jacobian has full rank

> 6. f is an diffeomorphism if for all $x \in U$, there exists an open set $U' \subseteq U$, and $f|_{U'}$ is bijective with continuously differentiable inverse.

I thought I understood the equivalent definitions, but when we started to do the exercise, something interesting happened. We were given the function $r(x,y) = y^2 - x^2$, and we would like to show that it is not a smooth sub-manifold at the origin (even if delete the origin).

Well, if we consider $S$ as the set of points $(x,y)$ satisfying $y^2-x^2 = 0$, then by evaluating the Jacobian it is easy to see that at the origin the Jacobian of $r$ is singular, but away from the origin $r$ is a valid submersion.

Here is where I get confused. The 3rd definition of a smooth sub-manifold can be interpreted like this, every point in a sub-manifold, locally, is a graph of a smooth function (our $\psi$ in the definition). Now if we consider the origin, by the third definition there should be an open set $ x \in \tilde{W} \in \mathbb{R}$, another open set $\tilde{V} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, and an injective immersion $\psi:\tilde{W} \to \tilde{V}$ such that the image of $\psi$ is $\tilde{V} \cap S$.

The argument given is that there is no such *homeomorphism* $\psi$, since deleting the origin from $\tilde{W}$ will give us 2 connected components in $\tilde{W}$, but 4 connected components in $\tilde{V}$. Thus we have violated the 3rd equivalent definition.

I am not sure where does this homeomorphism come from. For all we know, $\psi$ is just an injective immersion. It maps from a lower dimension to a higher dimension. So how do we know $\psi$ has a continuous inverse?